# CodeIgniter SQL Escaping Regexp Query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, escaping

I'm using CodeIgniter to query a sql database. I need to use a REGEXP in the where clause and I've read that it can be done with CodeIgniter Active Record but I can't get it to work. Even in the examples I saw the active record $this->db->where() has false as the 3rd parameter, meaning the data is not escaped. The solution I went with is just something like

```
$this->db->query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP 'pattern'");
```

The problem is that pattern contains some user input, for example if someone executed a search of the DB with the phrase "find me" the pattern would be something like

```
"find[\s\t\n]*me"
```

The potential here is for some malicious code to be entered instead of the words "find me". How can I escape this string? I've tried

```
$this->db->escape( "find[\s\t\n]*me" );
```

which produces an error because all of the backslashes are escaped, which I don't want. I've tried

```
$a = $this->db->escape( "find" );
$b = $this->db->escape( "me" )
$pattern = $a . "[\s\n\t]*" . $b;
$this->db->query( "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP $pattern");
```

but this also gives an error. Do I even need to worry about escaping this, or should I maybe do some validation on the JS side to make sure there is no malicious insertion instead?

Comment: read about  CI escapes queries: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries, hope that helps...

Comment: I've tried all of that. If i do $query = "SELECT id FROM entries WHERE title REGEXP '" . $ci->db->escape_like_str($regExp) . "'"; then I get SELECT id FROM entries WHERE title REGEXP 'what[\\s \n]*the[\\s \n]*hell. Notice the \\s double escaping is not what I desire, but I want to make sure that the words 'what' 'the' and 'hell' are all escaped. If i try to escape those words individually with $this->db->escape() i can't concatenate the results together because they're inside `   `